# CMake: suppress ALL warnings

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to do something extremely simple:

I have to work on a C++ project that raises a lot of compilation warnings.
Temporarily, I want to only see errors when I run make.
What do I need to add to my CMakeLists.txt to make that happen? The simpler, the better.

Comment: I'd rather make the compiler stop on the first error when I want to see it clear. Hiding all warnings sounds like a not so good idea

Comment: or rather treat warnings as errors. Then there are also no warnings that make it difficult to spot the errors ;)

Comment: An *error* be is a syntax error that prevents compilation. A *warning* is a potential runtime error and should never be ignored.

Comment: It might be a good idea to tag this question with the specific compiler you're using, since the answer depends on this. Judging by the answer you posted, I'm guessing it's either `clang` or `gcc`; but tagging might help someone else who stumbles onto this to find value in the question/answer

Comment: Can you just provide answer on how to ignore all warnings instead of giving advices nobody is looking for?

Answer (score 12):

It turns out the answer was to simply add the line

`add_definitions(-w)`

To CMakeLists.txt

It took me a lot longer than it should have to find this simple answer.

Comment: Don't use `add_definitions()`, It affects every single target. use `target_compile_options()` instead.

Comment: @Frank: But it is the purpose of the question - to affect on the **whole project**. Alternative could be setting `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` or `CMAKE_C_FLAGS`.

Comment: @Frank It doesn't affect *every single target*. It only affects targets defined in the same directory or in a subdirectory, and only ones defined _after_ the use (since this updates the directory property). The reason not to use `add_definitions` is because it should actually be `add_compile_options` in this case, since `add_definitions` is intended for preprocessor definitions.

Comment: Thank you Dugas for not giving an f about what other moan about this flag. This flag works and save so much headache and time when some developers decided to package the library that treated warnings as an error. Their version of compiler may work fine without warning, but newer or older version of compiler or different compiler generate different warning and thus crash the build unnecessarily.